# Buscar caracteres en una sección especifica del string PHP

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de reemplazar el caracter **>** por **#** que este dentro de la etiqueta HTML5 **code**. El problema es que se me reemplaza el caracter **>** de **code** y me da error en el codigo fuente HTML5.

Este es el string en la cual estoy buscando esos caracteres

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        if ($('>title_theme').val().length &gt= 1) {
            cargarArchivo(
                'POST',
                'http://labex.com/PostsController',
                'title_p=' + $('>title_theme').val()
            );
        }
```

El codigo anterior esta envuelto en la etiqueta **code** para ser mostrado como codigo snippet en mi pagina web.

```
$('>title_theme') El caracter > debe ser reemplazado por #
```

He intentado reemplazar el caracter > pero me cambia el caracter > del propio **code**, dando como resultado un error en el codigo fuente HTML5 (simplemente no se muestra el codigo snippet)

Empleo preg_replace para buscar y reemplazar

```
$simbolos = array(
                                    '/&lt;/uim',
                                    '/&gt;/uim',
                                    '/\<code\>/uim',
                                    '/&amp;\>\b39/uim',
                                    '/&amp;\bquot/uim',
                                    '/&amp;\blt/uim',
                                    '/&amp;\bgt/uim',
                                    '/\<\/code\>/uim',
                                );
                                $reemplazos = array(
                                    '<',
                                    '>',
                                    "<div class='code'><pre class='prettyprint'><code>",
                                    "'",
                                    '"',
                                    '&lt',
                                    '&gt',
                                    "</code></pre></div>",
                                );
                                $resultado = preg_replace($simbolos, $reemplazos, $request->getSend()->input('content'));
                                echo $resultado;
```

Sin los reemplazos de preg_replace el contenido se veria así:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        if ($(&amp;&gt;39&gt;title_theme&amp;&gt;39).val().length &amp;gt= 1) {
            cargarArchivo(
                &amp;&gt;39POST&amp;&gt;39,
                &amp;&gt;39http://labex.com/PostsController&amp;&gt;39,
                &amp;&gt;39title_p=&amp;&gt;39 + $(&amp;&gt;39&gt;title_theme&amp;&gt;39).val()
            );
        }
```

Intentando con el codigo:

```
$resultado=str_replace('>','#',html_entity_decode($request->getSend()->input('content')));
echo $resultado;
```

El resultaro seria el siguiente:

```
 <code#
window.setInterval(function(){
        if ($(&#39#title_theme&#39).val().length &gt= 1) {
            cargarArchivo(
                &#39POST&#39,
                &#39http://labex.com/PostsController&#39,
                &#39title_p=&#39 + $(&#39#title_theme&#39).val()
            );
        }
  </code#
```

Estaria bien reemplazar todos los # que esten entre **code** y **/code**, que no me reemplace los **<** y **>** de las etiquetas **code**

Comment: Hola, ya has intentado con `str_replace('>','#',$request->getSend()->input('content'))` ?

Comment: Si, y no me sirvió

Comment: Podrías hacer un `echo $request->getSend()->input('content')` para ver que es lo que contiene en ese momento?

Comment: ¿Habra una expresion regular que permita buscar a partir de cierto punto del string? De seguro esa es la solucion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolverlo debes usar `html_entity_decode()` para transformar todas las entidades HTML a sus caracteres correspondientes.

Luego aplicas el `str_replace()`:

```
$resultado=str_replace('>','#',html_entity_decode($request->getSend()->input('content')));
echo $resultado;
```

Luego para evitar que se cambie también la `>` en las etiquetas `<code>` puedes reemplazarlo una vez mas así:

```
$string=str_replace('>','#',html_entity_decode($request->getSend()->input('content')));
$resultado=str_replace('code#','code>',$string);
echo $resultado;
```

Para mas información puedes revisar [**la documentación**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Hola. No es lo que busco, te mostrare el resultado de tu respuesta

Comment: @JOSEHERRADA ya actualice la respuesta, puedo pensar en una solución con `preg_replace` también, de momento puedes probar con esta.

Comment: @JOSEHERRADA volví a actualizar la respuesta, ¿ya tienes algún resultado?

Answer (score 1):

Muy bien. Analizando el código que me dio una idea en las expresiones regulares de preg_replace. Dejare la respuesta

```
<?php 
                                $simbolos = array(
                                    '/&lt;/uim',
                                    '/&gt;/uim',
                                    '/\<code\>/uim',
                                    '/&amp;\>\b39/uim',
                                    '/&amp;\bquot/uim',
                                    '/&amp;\blt/uim',
                                    '/&amp;\bgt/uim',
                                    '/\>|\</uim', // Reemplazo todos los caracteres a #
                                    '/\#code\#/uim', // Las etiquetas #code# sera reemplazada por <code>
                                    '/\#\/code\#/uim', //La etiqueta de cierre #/code# sera reemplaza por </code>
                                    "/\#pre class='prettyprint'\#/uim" // Incluir el plugin prettify JS
                                );
                                $reemplazos = array(
                                    '<',
                                    '>',
                                    "<pre class='prettyprint'><code>",
                                    "'",
                                    '"',
                                    '&lt',
                                    '&gt',
                                    '#',
                                    '<code>',
                                    '</code></pre>',
                                    "<pre class='prettyprint'>"
                                );
                                $resultado = preg_replace($simbolos, $reemplazos, $request->getSend()->input('content'));
                                echo $resultado;
                            ?>
```

Se reemplaza todos los caracteres **<** y **>** por # (incluyendo **code** y **/code**), una vez reemplazados tenemos que reestablecer las etiquetas **code** y **/code** para que nos no de error en HTML, asi que se reemplaza con expresiones regulares.

Si hacemos lo anterior el resultado seria asi:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        if ($('#title_theme').val().length &gt= 1) {
            cargarArchivo(
                'POST',
                'http://labex.com/PostsController',
                'title_p=' + $('#title_theme').val()
            );
        }

$('#title_theme') // El caracter que salia antes > fue reemplazado por #, lo cual es correcto para codigo JQuery
```

> Me di cuenta que sale &gt en el codigo anterior, es porque lo copie del codigo fuente de la pagina, pero visualmente se veria asi:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        if ($('#title_theme').val().length >= 1) {
            cargarArchivo(
                'POST',
                'http://labex.com/PostsController',
                'title_p=' + $('#title_theme').val()
            );
        }
```

Comment: Bueno, te paso +1 por espíritu deportivo, aunque te aconsejo evitar usar muchas expresiones regulares, pueden hacer el funcionamiento del programa mas lento, procura usarlas como ultimo recurso, si es posible busca métodos alternativos, saludos.